# Thrift Nonblocking Server c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, thrift

Recently we replaced our internal messaging library with Apache Thrift. In our setup we have a couple of c# services and several c++ 'clients' who connect to them. In the beginning we used *TThreadPoolServer* for the server implementation.

```
_server = new TThreadPoolServer(processor, serverTransport);
```

Because it worked so well we also replaced our last server. This server needs to communicate with more than 400 clients. The problem we saw that as soon client number 100 connected our the server stopped accepting new connections and it did not even call c# timers. It kind of seem to choke till first clients disconnected.

By reading this SO [Large number of simulteneous connections in thrift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954945/large-number-of-simulteneous-connections-in-thrift) we decided to change to *TThreadedServer* and increased max number of threads to 500 and we have a working solution.

```
_server = new TThreadedServer(processor
    , serverTransport
    , new TTransportFactory()
    , new TTransportFactory()
    , new TBinaryProtocol.Factory()
    , new TBinaryProtocol.Factory()
    , 500
    , DebugLogThriftServer);
```

Still I would like to have the *TNonblockingServer* as it is implemented in the Thrift c++ library has. I was wondering if someone already wrote one for c#.

Answer (score 0):

This is an RPC framework that uses the standard thrift Protocol, and it is the same effect as using thrift IDL to define the service, that is, thrify can be compatible with code that uses thrift IDL, which is very helpful for cross-platform.

```
[ThriftStruct]
public class LogEntry
{

    [ThriftConstructor]
    public LogEntry([ThriftField(1)]String category, [ThriftField(2)]String message)
    {
        this.Category = category;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    [ThriftField(1)]
    public String Category { get; }

    [ThriftField(2)]
    public String Message { get; }
}

[ThriftService("scribe")]
public interface IScribe
{
    [ThriftMethod("getMessages")]
    List<LogEntry> GetMessages();

    [ThriftMethod]
    ResultCode Log(List<LogEntry> messages);
}

public class Scribe : IScribe
{
    public List<LogEntry> GetMessages()
    {
        return new List<LogEntry>
        {
            new LogEntry { Category = "c1", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
            new LogEntry { Category = "c2", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
            new LogEntry { Category = "c3", Message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
        };
    }

    public ResultCode Log(List<LogEntry> messages)
    {
        return ResultCode.TRY_LATER;
    }
}
```

you can try it: https://github.com/endink/Thrifty